# how to pass multiple admin class with iterable in django admin

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

```
from django.contrib import admin
from .models import Post, Comment, DataTracking
myModels = [Comment, DataTracking]
@admin.register(myModels, safe=True)
class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('name', 'body', 'post', 'created_on', 'active')
    list_filter = ('active', 'created_on')
    search_fields = ('name', 'email', 'body')
    actions = ['approve_comments']
    def approve_comments(self, request, queryset):
        queryset.update(active=True)
class DataTrackingAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('blogtitle','country','viewcount')
    list_filter = ('blogtitle','country')
    search_fields = ('blogtitle','country','viewcount')
class PostAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js=("injectjs.js",)
    list_display = ('title', 'slug', 'status','created_on')
    list_filter = ("status",)
    search_fields = ['title', 'content']
    prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',)}
admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)
```

## i am trying to this i want to register newly added DataTracking model with admin i tried passing both as seprate list admin class and itrables to admin register it gives me error

Comment: After Searching For entire 13 hours I understood the problem maybe I am a bad programmer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got it there is not a need to do it by itrables I can register it twice by using `admin.site.register(Post, PostAdmin)` and `admin.site.register(DataTracking, DataTrackingAdmin)` earlier when I tried to register them via this method I got error because I did this `admin.site.register(DataTracking, DataTracking)` and I had previously named both Admin class and model as DataTracking thats why it was giving me error so I began to look for `@admin.register()` method